# Disk block per table?

Tags: mysql, rdbms, blocking

1. At T1, insert comes for table_1, goes to disk block_1.
2. At T2, insert comes for table_2, can it go to same disk block_1(provided block_1 has space) or new block will be created per table ?
3. At T3, again insert comes for table_1, can it go either block_1 or block_2 based on available space ?

Comment: If by "disk block" you mean the database file page, a page can belong to one table only; you can't have records from different tables in the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnoDB (the default Engine in MySQL) allocates separate "blocks" for each table.

A "block" is 16KB, regardless of what size the OS or disk controller does.

Yes, a table with one small row is "wasting" a lot of disk space.  But if you have a million rows, the *percentage* waste will be lower.

Similarly, each `INDEX` (except for leaf nodes of the `PRIMARY KEY`) will use disk in blocks of 16KB.

Use this to see the "Data_length" and "Index_length":

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'T1';
```

I created a table with 2 secondary indexes, but have not put any rows in it yet:

```
mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'mod%'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: modification
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 0
 Avg_row_length: 0
    Data_length: 16384        -- one 16KB block for data
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 32768        -- two 16KB blocks, one per index
      Data_free: 0
  ...
```

Those 3 blocks belong to that one table; no sharing.